# Какой синтаксис запросов используется в Visual Studio при работе в С#?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM [Table_tovar] WHERE [id_category]=@id_category"
```

Почему квадратные скобки вместо круглых?
Как писать вложенные запросы?
Студия 2015

Comment: При чем здесь студия? Это обычный синтаксис SQL

Comment: В SQL скобки круглые

Comment: А это и не скобки...

Comment: Наверное это — http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29230. Но я не уверен что это, то что вы искали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Квадратные скобки - это "фишка" Transact SQL (диалекта SQL от Microsoft, используемого в Access и SQL Server). Они полностью аналогичны двойным кавычкам:

```
SELECT * FROM "Table_tovar" WHERE "id_category"=@id_category
```

Введены они в язык для представления идентификаторов которые не могут быть представлены иначе - например, без квадратных скобок (или двойных кавычек) невозможно сослаться на идентификатор который содержит пробел или ключевое слово:

```
SELECT [Name] FROM [Контактные данные]
```

Почему квадратные скобки а не кавычки? Наверное, это придумали чтобы запрос было проще записать внутри строкового литерала. Сравните:

```
var query1 = "SELECT [Name] FROM [Контактные данные]";
var query2 = "SELECT \"Name\" FROM \"Контактные данные\"";
var query3 =@"SELECT ""Name"" FROM ""Контактные данные""";
```

Наконец если вы спросите зачем вообще скобки вокруг идентификатора `Table_tovar` - то ответ будет "просто так". Очевидно что запрос автогенерированный, и разработчику генератора показалось проще ставить эти скобки всегда вместо того чтобы выяснять нужны ли они вообще. Конкретно ваш запрос можно записать вовсе безо всяких скобок:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_tovar WHERE id_category=@id_category
```

Comment: Ребят всем спасибо !

Comment: Особенно Павлу! Доходчиво и без всякого лишнего бахвальства)

Comment: @user293746 "Спасибы" на этой сайте принято выражать плюсом ответу, а "особенно спасибы" - зеленой галочкой возле ответа :-)

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос видимо касается t-sql. Квадратные скобки применяются когда вы хотите использовать в запросе ключевые(зарезервированные) слова.